# Distinguishing multiple keyboards in an Android application

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

I am working on an `Android` application, which has a custom keyboard inside it. Is there any way I could distinguish between the custom keyboard that I have in my application and the default one which is provided by Android ?

I want to know which keyboard whether it is default or custom which is opened ?